# Can the grc1leg command combine the legend for multiple kdensity plots in Stata?

Tags: legend, stata, kernel-density

I am creating kdensity curves for income (`kerr_income`) distributions in a year (`taxyear`) by gender (`male`). However, when I create the kdensity plot, I cannot combine the legend to differentiate by gender and not each curve. I want one legend to show a male and female distribution only.

```
kdensity kerr_income if male==0 & taxyear == 2008, addplot(kdensity kerr_income if male==1 & ///
taxyear == 2008) name(g1, replace) ///
legend(label(1 "Female") label(2 "Male")) 

kdensity kerr_income if male==0 & taxyear == 2009, legend(off) name(g2, replace) ///
addplot(kdensity kerr_income if male==1 & taxyear == 2009, legend(off) name(g3, replace) || ///
kdensity kerr_income if male==0 & taxyear == 2010, legend(off) name(g4, replace) || ///
kdensity kerr_income if male==1 & taxyear == 2010, legend(off) name(g5, replace)) 
grc1leg g1 g2 g3 g4 g5, legendfrom(g1)
```

I am using Stata 14. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried `grc1leg` on this kind of problem, or indeed much at all, but the problem you're facing can be avoided altogether. You need code so that you can exploit the `by()` option's scope for arranging all the scaffolding and cutting down the duplicate legends.

Here is a demonstration. Note that you need `multidensity` from SSC.

```
* want a 2 x 4 grouping 
sysuse auto, clear 
xtile qprice=price, nq(4)

preserve 

egen group = group(qprice foreign), label 
tab group 

* ssc install multidensity 
multidensity generate mpg, by(group) min(5) max(45) 
keep _x* _density* 
gen id = _n 
reshape long _density _x, i(id) j(g)

gen foreign = !mod(g, 2)
separate _density, by(foreign) 
label var _density0 "Domestic"
label var _density1 "Foreign"

gen G = ceil(g/2)
line _density? _x, by(G, note("Quartile bins of price")) sort xla(5(10)45) xtitle(Miles per gallon) ytitle(Density) name(demo, replace)

restore
```

[image]